# Почему на некоторых координатах не находит пересечение?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Почему может функция поиска пересечения отрезка с отрезком работать корректно с целыми числами и не корректно с дробными? С помощью `D3` сделал **зум**, и заметил, что на некоторых точках функция `line_line_intersect` не находит пересечение, хотя оно есть и его видно визуально. Добавил **Math.round** и всё находит — всегда. Почему?

```
function btwn(a, b1, b2) {

  if ((a >= b1) && (a <= b2)) { return true; }
  if ((a >= b2) && (a <= b1)) { return true; }
  return false;

}

function line_line_intersect(line1, line2) {

  console.log('line1: ',line1[0].x, line1[0].y, line1[1].x, line1[1].y);
  console.log('line2: ',line2[0].x, line2[0].y, line2[1].x, line2[1].y);

  let x1 = Math.round(line1[0].x), x2 = Math.round(line1[1].x), x3 = Math.round(line2[0].x), x4 = Math.round(line2[1].x);
  let y1 = Math.round(line1[0].y), y2 = Math.round(line1[1].y), y3 = Math.round(line2[0].y), y4 = Math.round(line2[1].y);
  // let x1 = line1[0].x, x2 = line1[1].x, x3 = line2[0].x, x4 = line2[1].x;
  // let y1 = line1[0].y, y2 = line1[1].y, y3 = line2[0].y, y4 = line2[1].y;
  let pt_denom = (x1 - x2) * (y3 - y4) - (y1 - y2) * (x3 - x4);
  let pt_x_num = (x1*y2 - y1*x2) * (x3 - x4) - (x1 - x2) * (x3*y4 - y3*x4);
  let pt_y_num = (x1*y2 - y1*x2) * (y3 - y4) - (y1 - y2) * (x3*y4 - y3*x4);
  if (pt_denom == 0) { return /* "parallel"*/ false; }
  else {
    let pt = {'x': pt_x_num / pt_denom, 'y': pt_y_num / pt_denom};
    if (btwn(pt.x, x1, x2) && btwn(pt.y, y1, y2) && btwn(pt.x, x3, x4) && btwn(pt.y, y3, y4)) { return pt; }
    else { return /*"not in range"*/ false; }
  }

}
```

Координаты на которых не отрабатывает функция:

```
line1:  31.362548828125 150.78750610351562 31.362548828125 299.21250610351564
line2:  0.787506103515625 214.96249389648438 111.71250610351564 214.96249389648438
```

Comment: Результаты вещественной арифметики не совсем точны, это часто сказывается в задачах вычислительной геометрии. Но что это за странное условие внутри предпоследнего else?

Comment: @MBo функция подсмотрена https://bl.ocks.org/bricof/f1f5b4d4bc02cad4dea454a3c5ff8ad7, насколько я понимаю, проверяем принадлежность получившейся точки прямым.

Comment: если бы вы привели данные, при которых наблюдается сбой, было бы легче сказать где ошибка

Comment: Угу, понял, это не совсем принадлежность отрезку, а проверка, что точка пересечения не лежит за пределами ограничивающего прямоугольника. В общем, погрешности, скорее всего, влияют. При малых углах между отрезками они будут велики.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, обновил вопрос

Comment: @MBo ответ можете дать?

Comment: @doox911 поздравляю Вас с круглой репой :)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, Спасибо) Это одна из целей на этот год) Выполнена досрочно)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Результаты вычислений с использованием вещественной арифметики не являются абсолютно точными.

Это часто сказывается в задачах вычислительной геометрии - например, при нахождении точки пересечения линий, как в данной задаче, погрешность нахождения координат точки при малом угле между прямыми может привести к ошибкам - незначительные, казалось бы, погрешности вызывают смещение рассчитанной точки вдоль прямой на заметное расстояние.

Если нужен только факт пересечения, есть более устойчивый алгоритм - для всех концов отрезков определяется, лежат ли они по разные стороны от прямой, содержащей другой отрезок (с использованием векторного произведения). Если же нужна точка пересечения - деваться некуда.

Один из ваших отрезков горизонтален, другой вертикален. Разность координат (в одном случае x, в другом y) нулевая, и рассчитанная точка, видимо, не попадает в диапазон нулевой ширины (например, рассчитанное значение pt.x=31.36254882812**4** сравнивается с 31.36254882812**5**).  Сравнивайте с допуском.

```js
function btwn(a, b1, b2) {
  if ((a >= b1 - 0.0000001) && (a <= b2 + 0.0000001)) { return true; }
  if ((a >= b2 - 0.0000001) && (a <= b1 + 0.0000001)) { return true; }
  return false;
}

function line_line_intersect(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4) {
  let pt_denom = (x1 - x2) * (y3 - y4) - (y1 - y2) * (x3 - x4);
  let pt_x_num = (x1*y2 - y1*x2) * (x3 - x4) - (x1 - x2) * (x3*y4 - y3*x4);
  let pt_y_num = (x1*y2 - y1*x2) * (y3 - y4) - (y1 - y2) * (x3*y4 - y3*x4);
  if (pt_denom === 0) { return /* "parallel"*/ false; }
  else {
    let pt = {'x': pt_x_num / pt_denom, 'y': pt_y_num / pt_denom};
    //console.log(pt_denom, pt_x_num, pt_y_num);
    if (btwn(pt.x, x1, x2) && btwn(pt.y, y1, y2) && btwn(pt.x, x3, x4) && btwn(pt.y, y3, y4)) { return pt; }
    else { return /*"not in range"*/ false; }
  }
}

console.log(line_line_intersect(31.362548828125, 150.78750610351562,
                                31.362548828125, 299.21250610351564,
                                 0.787506103515625, 214.96249389648438,
                                 111.71250610351564, 214.96249389648438))
```

Comment: Из вашего ответа не понятно, как решить данную проблему. Точка нужна.

Comment: Добавил возможный вариант.

Comment: Не работает) По прежнему нет пересечений.

Comment: Нужно проверить переменные на каждом шаге

Comment: У меня работает, код добавил

Comment: Я косяк. Работает. Почему только `0.0000001`?

Comment: В принципе допуск `eps` подбирается согласно амплитуде величин, которые сравниваются. Для точности Double это примерно `10^-12*Amp`, т.е. для приведённых значений можно сравнивать модуль разности с `10^-9`

Comment: Что такое `eps` и `Amp`?

Comment: eps - epsylon - обычное обозначение допуска. Amp - абсолютное значение амплитуды величин